# Error „No migrations were applied. The database is already up to date“

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqlite, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm building a web app using razor pages, and EF with SQLite. I'm developing under Linux with the CORE SDK.

After adding an initial migration without problems `dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate`. When I update the database I get a message saying No migrations were applied. The database is already up to date...

And when I check the database using SQLite command interpreter (or run the app), the database does not contain any tables except an empty migrations history table. `__EFMigrationsHistory`.

The info message I got when I run dotnet ef migrations add

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[0]
User profile is available. Using '/home/vagrant/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys' as key repository; keys will not be encrypted at rest.
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
Entity Framework Core 2.0.1-rtm-125 initialized 'AgentContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite' with options: None
Done. To undo this action, use 'ef migrations remove
```

The output message I get when running dotnet ef database update.

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[0]
User profile is available. Using '/home/vagrant/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys' as key repository; keys will not be encrypted at rest.
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
Entity Framework Core 2.0.1-rtm-125 initialized 'AgentContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite' with options: None
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
Executed DbCommand (11ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
Executed DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
Executed DbCommand (6ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
CREATE TABLE "__EFMigrationsHistory" (
"MigrationId" TEXT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT "PK___EFMigrationsHistory" PRIMARY KEY,
"ProductVersion" TEXT NOT NULL
);
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
Executed DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
Executed DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
Executed DbCommand (2ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "sqlite_master" WHERE "name" = '__EFMigrationsHistory' AND "type" = 'table';
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
Executed DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
Executed DbCommand (3ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT "MigrationId", "ProductVersion"
FROM "__EFMigrationsHistory"
ORDER BY "MigrationId";
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations[20405]
No migrations were applied. The database is already up to date.
No migrations were applied. The database is already up to date.
Done.
```

The database context:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Archive.Models
{
    public class AgentContext : DbContext
    {
        public AgentContext (DbContextOptions<AgentContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Agent> Agent  { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The Model

```
using System;

namespace Archive.Models
{
    public class Agent
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Departement { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I tried to delete the Migrations manually and start over but the problem persist.

[The entire code](https://github.com/Iduoad/asp-test)

Comment: The link for code is broken. Try to delete the **empty database** and **migrations**, re-run the command, what is the migration file and the database result.

Comment: Sorry I've added a dot in the link to the code. The url works now.

I deleted The Migrations and the database, and re-tried, I got the same messages.